# ASP.NET MVC: Custom Validation by DataAnnotation base on two fields length

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have this JS method that I am using to do some validation. But I wanted to see if I can build a Custom Validation by DataAnnotation. Is there a way for me to collect this information so I can use it in a custom validation? And will this do JS validation?

JS code I want to replace

```js
function materialsconfirmhasError() {
    let materialsconfirm = $('input[name="ckmaterialsconfirm"]:checked').length > 0;
    let uploadcontrol = $("#upImport").data("kendoUpload"),
        files = uploadcontrol.getFiles();

    let FileLink = $("#txtFileLink").val();
    console.log(FileLink);
    if (files.length !== 0 || FileLink.length !== 0) {
        if (materialsconfirm == false) {
            $("#lblConfirmError").show();
            return true
        } else {
            $("#lblConfirmError").hide();
            return false
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="materialsconfirm" class="form-check">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.materialsconfirm,new { id= "ckmaterialsconfirm", @class= "form-control" })
            @*<label for="ckmaterialsconfirm"> I have read and adhered to the above statements</label>*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label id="lblConfirmError" class="text-danger field-validation-error" style="display:none">Please Confirm.</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model

```cs
[Display(Name = "I have read and adhered to the above statements")]
[CustomMaterialValidator]
public Boolean materialsconfirm { get; set; }
```

CustomMaterialValidator

```cs
 public class CustomMaterialValidator: ValidationAttribute {
     protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {
         if (value != null) {
             bool flgCustomMaterial = value is bool ? (bool) value : false;

             if (flgCustomMaterial == true) {
                 return ValidationResult.Success;
             } else {

             }

             return new ValidationResult("Please Confirm.");
         }
         return new ValidationResult("Please Confirm.");
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom `ValidationAttribute` that reads other properties from your model. You can do so using the `ValidationContext` available to you in your overload of the `IsValid` method.

You can access a different property this way:

```
    var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("OtherPropertyName");
    if (otherPropertyInfo == null) {
        return new ValidationResult("The other property doesn't exist");
    }

    object otherPropertyValue = otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
```

In this example, the value will be in `otherPropertyValue` and you can implement the validations you need using this value along with the `value` of your annotated property (`materialsconfirm` in your case).

You can make this attribute work on the client side by signaling from your `ValidationAttribute` that it has client side validation and creating a jQuery validator for it, as illustrated [here](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/d80b2b90-847b-4c5b-90ac-c2db18e131be.aspx), but that will require you to translate your validation logic into JS.

If you want these validations to happen on the client side using server-side logic, you can  implement the `[Remote]` attribute which lets you specify an action that will be called to validate the property. You can also specify additional properties that will be used to perform the validation. You can find some examples on how to implement this option including additional properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#additional-fields). The downside is that this validation is not enforced on the server.

Comment: would this get trigger at the Controllers level on would it be in the JS like `var isvalid = _form.valid();`?`

Comment: At the controller level, when the form is posted and model validations are enforced.

Comment: I was thinking DataAnnotation is both client and server side?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a couple of additional options available. There's no silver bullet here, but hopefully one of these options will suit you.